# Vue.js error in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, vue.js

When I try to run the following code in Laravel with vue.js:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Include roboto.css to use the Roboto web font, material.css to include the theme and ripples.css to style the ripple effect -->
    <link href="/css/roboto.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/ripples.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2> Locaties </h2>
            </div>
            <data list="{{ json_encode($locations) }}"></data>
        </div>      
    </div>

    <template id="ln-data">
        <ul>
            <li v-for="item in list">@{{ item.name }}</li>
        </ul>
    </template>
<script>
    new Vue({
      el: 'body'
    })  

    Vue.component('data', {
        template: '#ln-data',
        props:['list']
    })
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.common.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/ripples.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/material.min.js"></script>

<style>
.newclient {
    display:none;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

I receive the following errors in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined(anonymous function) @
>   vue.common.js:981 vue.common.js:9157 Uncaught TypeError: this._init is
>   not a function

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You import the vue.common.js (CommonJS bundle distributed on NPM). Change it to vue.js and see if it works. Also, put your own <script> to the bottom of your imports, because it depends on the vue.js import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Changes to your version:

- vue.js imported instead of vue.common.js
- moved your own `<script>...</script` to the bottom of the imports because it depends on the vue.js import
- activate the vue debug mode while developping makes it easier to find errors.

  ```
  <html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title></title>
      <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Include roboto.css to use the Roboto web font, material.css to include the theme and ripples.css to style the ripple effect -->
      <link href="/css/roboto.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="/css/material.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="/css/ripples.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>

      <div class="container col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h2> Locaties </h2>
              </div>
              <data list="{{ json_encode($locations) }}"></data>
          </div>      
      </div>

      <template id="ln-data">
          <ul>
              <li v-for="item in list">@{{ item.name }}</li>
          </ul>
      </template>

      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/ripples.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/material.min.js"></script>
      <script>
          // vuejs debug mode
          Vue.config.debug = true; //TODO: Remove in production


          new Vue({
            el: 'body'
        })  

          Vue.component('data', {
              template: '#ln-data',
              props:['list']
          })
      </script>
      <style>
          .newclient {
              display:none;
          }
      </style>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```